# MFC ColorButton takes a very long time to respond

Tags: c++, colors, mfc, dialog

I'm writing a simple program in MFC that draws a a pattern according to a function.

I've added support for changing colors of the graphics. However, in the dialog, when the user tries to select the color button to see the color choices, the drop-down takes an abnormally long time to show up and appears frozen for about 5 seconds.

Nothing is being rendered in the meantime, nor are there any other obvious processes that might be slowing things down.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Make sure you're not in debug mode.

Comment: I am in debug mode. Why would that make a difference?

Comment: It may be a problem with the color picker control being in a DLL that hasn't been loaded yet. Try testing in release mode or without the debugger attached.

Comment: Interesting thinking.... it helped a little bit